# Sorting of scala hashmap using integer key is not working

Tags: scala, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to list the latest file in the array object using HashMap in scala.
The key is the file number and value is the file name. When I sort the hashmap by key, it always seems to return the 1st filename that was inserted. So, x always returns `"hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_8.txt"`

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

val status = Array("hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_8.txt", "hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_8.txt", "hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_7.txt", "hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_10.txt", "hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_9.txt")

      var x = ""
      var newFile: String = ""
      val hMap: HashMap[Int, String] = HashMap.empty[Int, String]
      if (!status.isEmpty) {
        for (e ← status) {
          val counter = Try { e.toString.split("_")(1).split("\\.")(0) }.getOrElse("1")
          hMap.put(counter.toInt, e.toString)
        }
        x = HashMap(hMap.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 > _._1): _*).head._2
        }
```

Comment: Why are you putting the sorted sequence back in a new HashMap which doesn't keep the order. Simply use `x = hMap.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 > _._1).head._2` instead

Comment: Wow. Thanks for pointing that out. I am still not able to think through when it comes to scala.

Comment: @Tammy There are lots of handy methods in Scala, and lots of different ways to achieve similar purposes. However it's useful to know that in all languages, a hash map does not maintain order (except special implementations such as linked hash maps which are ordered but not sorted). Tree maps are sorted though. These are abstract data structures that do not depend on the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a map for this, let alone a mutable one. Don't need sort either.
Something like this should do what you want:

```
val x = status.minBy { _.replaceAll(".*_(\\d+).*", "$1").toInt }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dima suggests, you could use the minBy, but use it with caution. That method will throw an exception when status is an empty list.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.minBy
```

Considering that, maybe you could use the **sortBy** method, combining it with the **headOption**:

```
status.sortBy(_.replaceAll(".*_(\\d+).*", "$1").toInt).headOption
```

So, using your given array, the result would be

```
Some(hdfs://localhost:8020/transactions/transaction_7.txt)
```

And if the array happens to be empty, you would end up with a **None**